# Is it possible to use activities and services of a library project in other projects?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-library

I am in a situation, where need to work with several common classes, services and activities to be used in two projects. Thus, willing to know how can I use those common services as well as activities in them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use library project to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Just add your library project as a library to the main project and add an activity to a manifest file like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.yourlibrary.package.ActivityName"
        android:label="@string/name" >
    </activity>
```

After that you can reference to this activity just as if it one of the main's project activities.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create New Library Project with those common classes and services.
2. Use this library project as reference in another project